# Smoothing out angular object in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I imported this object from an .stl file which I created in SolidWorks. I need to export it in a .raw format for further use. But the object is a bit too angular. Is there any way I can smooth it out using blender?

[image: photo of the object]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. In the object mode select the object then there is option "subdivide surface" in the "Add Modifier", as shown in figure at right by red color point 1, after selecting it,
2. Click the view untill "view 2" as you can see I have View 1 in point 2 written in red color
3. At left you will see the smooth the press that smooth option

Comment: I was looking for something like this! Thank you.

Comment: This will introduce far more geometry than is needed. See [my answer below](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75180/28015) for a better approach.

Comment: Even if you don't want to do this much just go to "object mode" select your object then just click "smooth" at left. No much work needed. BTW I am new to blend therefore provided you what I used with my experience. ;-)

Thanks @pycoder, this is really good to know!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to introduce additional geometry here. Use smooth shading, then turn on auto smooth in the mesh settings.

[image]

[Download the blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2893/)

Comment: I don't think that would work. The file is going to be exported as a `.raw` file which doesn't support smooth shading, let alone *Auto Smooth*.

Comment: @ScottMilner Just adding geometry is not the correct way to accomplish this. If you are sure that the .raw format doesn't support normals, then the proper solution would be to adapt the shader used to render it from the end of whatever imports it. The "more geometry" solution won't fix the problem...it just makes it look better. Incidentally, the other answer uses smooth shading as well ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what @menrva's purpose with this is, but the `.raw` file is just a list of 10 numbers per face: three coordinate points and a normal vector per triangle. If they are wanting to render it, then your solution would be fine. For 3D printing, though, more geometry is the only solution. Also, smooth shading doesn't change the outline of an object, and the sharp edges could still be seen in close up rendering.

Comment: @ScottMilner Interesting about the .raw format...I've never used it before. Regarding 3D printing, that is correct, but the two scenarios that you gave are very specialized, so my answer still works as *a* way to do this. On the other hand, a plain subsurf modifier will not have the correct form at all. You need bevel or edge split, etc. to make it work.